# Turning Equation Into Function?

Tags: python

I need to turn following equation into a python function.

```
k = people[i]
i = people[j]

costs[i][j]
costs[j][k]

change = -costs[i][k] - costs[j][l] + costs[i][l] + cost[j][k]
```

Comment: Okay. Sounds like a good plan. What's your question?

Comment: Which of those variables is an argument to the function?

Comment: I'm trying to define change as a function. How do I turn the above equation into a function?

Comment: as a function of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is:

```
def change(i,j,costs,people):
  k = people[i]
  l = people[j] # was originally i = people[j] but unsure where l comes from otherwise
  result = -costs[i][k] - costs[j][l] + costs[i][l] + cost[j][k]
  return result
```

(and then call with:
  `mychange = change(i,j,costs,people)`
)

Note that if my assumption on where l comes from is wrong, change that 3rd line back to i = people[j] and pass in l as well.

Also note that using l as a variable is a bad idea as it's rather hard to tell apart from 1 (and also, using i,j,k,l is bad when you could use a more descriptive value to make it clearer what this means)